# Tooltip from database for a listbox

Tags: php, html, database, tooltip

I have a listbox. My listbox shows all my *IDs* from a database but I want to create a listbox, and when I mouseover it the tooltip shows the name associated with ID in the database. Here is the code of my listbox :

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ohmega', 'zabbix', 'lol');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from taches');
        $stmt->execute();

                ?>  
                <span id="productSKUHelp" class="helpTip questionMark"></span>




                    <select id="tache" name="tache">        
                    <?php

                        $stmt->execute();
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo '<option>'.$row['tacId'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
```

So how do I put a tooltip linked with my Id of my listbox?

Comment: You want tooltip when you hover an option in dropdown?

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you have generated following select option;

```
<select multiple class="tooltip">
    <option title="potato">1</option>
    <option title="tomato">3</option>
    <option title="apple">40</option>
    <option title="strawberry">100</option>
</select>
```

You can use following js;

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip();
```

Here is working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/JWdpf/1/)**

Comment: First that not what I expected. You're tooltip work after you selected a item. I want it when the list is there. 2) My list come from my database so no option definied. Third All my tooltip need to be associated Id and Name. Exemple my listbox show 1,3,40, 100 from my database ID and when i'm hover 1 they show potato over 3, show tomato. Id associate with name.

Comment: I've try this but nothing happen :  `code
    <span id="productSKUHelp" class="helpTip questionMark"></span>
    
 
    
    
     <select id="select" title="tooltip">  
     <?php

      $stmt->execute();
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo '<option value="'.$row['tacName'].'">'.$row['tacId'].'</option>'."\n";
      }
     ?>
     </select> 
  



<script type="text/javascript">



 $(function () {
      $("select").tooltip({
          content: function () {
              return $(this).val();
          }
      });
  });
`

Comment: Here the asnwer  `code     
<!-- début section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->     
     <label title="Select your state">Tache: <select title="Select your state" id="state" name="state">
     <?php

      $stmt->execute();
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo ' <option title="';
       echo $row['tacName'];
       echo '">';
       echo $row['tacId'];
       echo '</option>'."\n";
       //echo '<option value="'.$row['tacName'].'">'.$row['tacId'].'</option>'."\n";
      }
     ?>
</select>
</label>
<!-- Fin section cobobox tache avec tool tip --> `.

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon You can see my updated answer. Btw, you shouldn't paste huge code blocks in comment section. Please state it in your question.